# The limit of $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+n\ln(1+x^2)}dx$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

The task is to calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+n\ln(1+x^2)}dx$$ I tried various estimates I know to find the dominating integrable function and **nothing** worked. Does anyone have any idea? Is this even an application of DCT or something else?

Comment: $$ x^2 - \frac{x^4}{2} \leq \log(1+x^2) \leq x^2$$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$

Comment: @WillJagy, I know this, thanks, but I wasn't able to use it to construct a dominating function...

Comment: Poppy, I see that you like Jack's answer. Meanwhile, both integrals can be **explicitly calculated,** the one where $\log(1+x^2)$ is replaced by $x^2,$ that one is not hard and, I think, appears in Jack's answer, and the other one with $\log(1+x^2)$ is replaced by $x^2 - \frac{x^4}{2},$ a bit more difficult but still just rational rational functions.

Comment: Oh, well. The harder integral can be done with partial fractions. I did ask an online service for the indefinite integral but there was an unfortunate sign choice, could not be used in the supplied form for this problem. After an hour I suppose I have the correct form, but still not quite the actual integral. Well, it can be done, just more time than I have today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DCT as Discrete Cosine Transform? I cannot understand what you are meaning.

Anyway, your integral converges towards $\frac{\pi}{2}$, since:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+n\log(1+x^2)}\,dx \geq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+nx^2}\,dx = \arctan(\sqrt{n})=\frac{\pi}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right),$$
while the difference between the first and the second integral is bounded by:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}&&n^{3/2}(1-\log 2)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4\,dx}{(1+nx^2)(1+n\log(1+x^2))}\\&\leq& n^{3/2}(1-\log 2)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4 \,dx}{(1+n\log(1+x^2))^2}\\&\leq&n^{3/2}(1-\log 2)\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4 \,dx}{(1+nx^2-\frac{n}{2}x^4)^2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
where:
$$\frac{x^4}{(1+nx^2-\frac{n}{2}x^4)^2}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}\text{ for }x\in[0,1/\sqrt{n}],$$
$$\frac{x^4}{(1+nx^2-\frac{n}{2}x^4)^2}\leq \frac{1}{n^2(1-\frac{1}{2}x^2)^2}\leq\frac{4}{n^2}\text{ for }x\in[1/\sqrt{n},1],$$
hence:

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1+n\log(1+x^2)}\,dx =\frac{\pi}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right).$$

Comment: believe Dominated Convergence Theorem  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem although this example requires only Riemann integration

Comment: Thanks a lot, very nice solution! I will wait for some time and then accept it!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> Heuristically, when $\ds{n \ggg 1}$, the main contribution to the integral comes from $\ds{x \gtrsim 0}$ such that

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}{\root{n} \over 1 + n\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}}}\,\dd x
\sim\int_{0}^{1}{\root{n} \over 1 + nx^{2}}\,\dd x
=\arctan\pars{\root{n}} = {\pi \over 2} - \arctan\pars{1 \over \root{n}}
\\[3mm]&\stackrel{n \to \infty}{\to} \color{#66f}{\large{\pi \over 2}} \approx {\tt 1.5708}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps, but isn't a strict proof (using tools I want to use) I was hoping for.

Comment: @Poppy I know that. However, it's the first it comes to our mind just by looking the integral. It's a good thing to know in advance the solution. In that way we can refine every thing. For those reason I started with the word "Heuristically". What are you looking for ${\tt\mbox{@Jack D'Aurizio}}$ [already did't](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/927057/85343) in a rigourous fashion. Thanks.